# Scrolling through Visual Studio Solution Explorer without mouse or keyboard arrows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, key-bindings

I would like to navigate through the solution explorer of Visual Studio (2019) without using the arrow-keys or the mouse. I already tried remapping the Edit.LineUp/Down with "Use new shortcut in:" global and solution explorer but I it's not working with my specified keys (Ctrl+j/k).

Am I using the wrong command or is my desired behavior simply not possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to try to do this?

Comment: Because I would love to keep my hands on the home row and don't move my right hand to the arrows and back.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a non-Visual-Assist solution. Ultimately, your reasons boil down to "open a file quickly" without elaboration. Adding a file, changing its properties, adding a filter or folder, etc, to the solution all require using the mouse at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [Visual Assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/) (It's great and every visual studio user should have it!)
2. `Shift + Alt + O` to `Open a file in Solution...`
3. Type most or all of the filename until only one is left
4. Press `Enter`

---

If you don't want to use Visual Assist, there is a built-in solution `Go To > File` via `Ctrl + Shift + T`.

This will open a search bar where you can type in a filename and it will perform a similar feature but not as powerful.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. Your second suggestion is what I'm using for now. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AlexFischer If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as Accepted by clicking the check mark in the top left. :)